# Is there a home for a question on calculating cost of using Storage as a Service?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, scope

There is a lot of hype being generated by the distributed storage solutions:

- [Maidsafe](https://maidsafe.net/)
- [Storj](https://storj.io/)
- [Sia](http://sia.tech/)

They (supposedly) offer low-cost storage, and also pay for people to share their storage for others to use.

However, it is *extremely* difficult to find out how much it costs in everyday money to use these systems (or how much one would get paid), as they are based around their own crypto-currencies (which prices are often quoted in Bitcoin to add further obfuscation). The duration of storage adds further complexity to making a comparison.

As such, it's extremely difficult to know how much each service costs or pays out individually, and even more difficult or to make a fair comparison between them.

In my searches, people are looking for some real-world figures and/or a way to calculate them - but they are not readily available.

I would like to ask a question along the lines of:

> How can I work out which is the cheapest storage solution [of the three], based on storing 1TB of data for a month?

I tried to ask the analogous question with respect to earnings [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1150176/earnings-in-usd-terabyte-month-of-storj-vs-maidsafe-vs-sia?noredirect=1#comment1653451_1150176) but it was closed as off-topic.

I feel that this question would add value in clarifying very murky waters, but I'm not sure where to post it, or even if it would be on-topic for any SE site.

If it's not on-topic for SE, any pointers as to where to ask it outside?

Comment: The problem with such questions is that hey go stale very soon. At best you can ask for a general approach but that becomes more of a math problem ....

Comment: I agree that the method of finding out the answer is more important than the answer for today (teach a person to fish and all).

I'd be *very* happy with math variable source data and the formulae to operate upon them - there really is diddly out there when it comes to any basis of comparison.